# Online Restaurant Ordering/Billing System

Tags: online-payment

I'm looking for an online restaurant system that would allow the personnel to use it to serve customers. It needs to have a way to have a stack of different products and prices for the employee to select from. The selected items will go in a new order, however, this order can stay open for the cases where a table keeps ordering new items before asking for the check. Thus the software should allow for multiple orders to be open at the same time, easily manageable by the employee as there will be multiple clients being served at the same time.

There are plenty of Online Ordering Systems out there, however, they cannot handle the multiple open orders at the same time which is essential for the specific task that I have. It would be a great bonus if the solution is open source / PHP but at this point I'd look at anything that would eventually do the trick.

Thank you!